# How to add xmlns namespaces to urlset in sitemap xml

Tags: xml, xslt, sitemap

I have sitemap xml:

```
<urlset>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.somedomain.com</loc>
    <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    <priority>1</priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

I am creating it using `xslt` and I need the `urlset` to have namespace attaributes:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
    xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"
    xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
```

How can I add them?

This is my `xslt` snippet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
    xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:element name = "urlset">
        <!-- xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"
        xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1"-->

<xsl:call-template name="drawNodes">  
<xsl:with-param name="parent" select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@isDoc and @level=1]"/>  
</xsl:call-template>

    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

**EDIT**

This is edited snippet after @michael.hor257k answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"  
  xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>

<!-- update this variable on how deep your site map should be -->
<xsl:variable name="maxLevelForSitemap" select="6"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:call-template name="urlset"> </xsl:call-template>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="urlset">
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
    xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"
    xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
        <!-- more code here -->

    <xsl:call-template name="drawNodes">  
        <xsl:with-param name="parent" select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@isDoc and @level=1]"/>  
    </xsl:call-template>
    </urlset>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="drawNodes">
<xsl:param name="parent"/> 
<xsl:if test="umbraco.library:IsProtected($parent/@id, $parent/@path) = 0 or (umbraco.library:IsProtected($parent/@id, $parent/@path) = 1 and umbraco.library:IsLoggedOn() = 1)">
    <xsl:for-each select="$parent/* [@isDoc and @level &lt;= $maxLevelForSitemap and (umbracoNaviHide != '1' or not(umbracoNaviHide))]">
    <xsl:if test="@id &gt; 0">
        <xsl:if test="not(umbracoRedirect) or umbracoRedirect = ''">
            <xsl:element name="url">
                <xsl:element name="loc">
                    <xsl:variable name="url" select="concat('http://',umbraco.library:RequestServerVariables('HTTP_HOST'))" />
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat($url,umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id))" />
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="changefreq">
                    <xsl:if test="sitemapChange != ''">
                        <xsl:value-of select="sitemapChange" />
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="not(sitemapChange) or sitemapChange = ''">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="@level &lt;= 2">weekly</xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="@level &gt;= 3">monthly</xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="@level &gt;= 4">weekly</xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>yearly</xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="priority">
                    <xsl:if test="not(sitemapChange) or sitemapChange = ''">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="@level &lt;= 2">1</xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="@level &gt;= 3">0.9</xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="@level &gt;= 4">0.8</xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>0.7</xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:call-template name="drawNodes">    
            <xsl:with-param name="parent" select="."/>    
        </xsl:call-template>

    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>


</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Still it outputs `url` with empty xmlns namespace.

**EDIT 2**

Even if I do a simple code like here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [
  <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;">
]>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">

  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:call-template name="urlset" />

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="urlset">
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
    xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"
    xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">

      <xsl:call-template name="url">
      </xsl:call-template>

    </urlset>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="url">
    <url>


    </url>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I still get empty namespace in `url`:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1" xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
  <url xmlns="" />
</urlset>
```

Which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/urlset">
    <urlset
    xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"
    xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
        <!-- more code here -->
    </urlset>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then in your named template, change all your `xsl:element` instructions to literal result elements - for example, instead of:

```
<xsl:element name="url">
    <!-- more code here -->
</xsl:element>
```

do:

```
<url>
    <!-- more code here -->
</url>
```

Comment: I have applied it but now `url` tags have added `xmlns=""` empty namespace

Comment: Thta's because you're not putting them in a namespace. Edit your question and show a [mcve].

Comment: here you go - edited. Should I have at all xmlns namespace in url tag?

Comment: Running the posted code does not reproduce the problem. Anyway have a look at my edited answer.

Comment: With even simple code I get an empty `xmlns` in `url` tag - see my edit 2 above. @micheal.hor257k

Comment: That's because you have missed the move of the default namespace declaration to the `xsl:stylesheet` start-tag.

Comment: That was it. Thanks!